# Why does gcc -### proc.c not show the invocation of the preprocessor?

Tags: gcc, command-line-arguments, preprocessor

I was under the (possibly errononously) assumption that I can use `gcc -###` to display which commands gcc executes when it compiles a translation unit.

However, when I execute `gcc -### prog.c`, I am not shown an invocation of the preprocessor `/usr/bin/cpp`.

So, is my assumption wrong or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc has changed the implementation of the preprocessor. It's no longer an independent program. `cc1` now handles both preprocessing and compiling. A command called `cpp` still exists, but it's just a special mode of `cc1` and it's only there for backward compatibility with scripts that use `cpp` as a general purpose macro processor.